# Como comparar o valor dentro de um <span></span> e disparar uma ação?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como obter o valor dentro deste span?

```
<span id="Preço">199,00</span>
```

Preciso compará-lo com outro, para que dispare uma ação quando for maior que 199,00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com jQuery você pode testar desta forma:

```
if( parseInt( $('#Preco').text() ) > 199 )
```

Com JS Puro, pode testar assim:

```
if( parseInt( document.getElementById('preco').innerHTML ) > 199 )
```

Mas tome cuidado com os centavos. Como mencionado pelo @bfavaretto, se você tiver `199,50` o resultado não será esperado, pois o decimal em JS é separado por `.`. A solução seria trocar a `,` por `.` e usar [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

```
var preco = $('#Preco').text();
preco = parseFloat( preco.replace( '.', '' ).replace( ',', '.' ) ); // solução do @bfavaretto
if( preco > 199 ) { ...
```

Outra coisa: dê preferência a não usar acentuação nos IDs dos elementos, para evitar bugs e incompatibilidades diversas.

### Demo:

```js
var preco = $('#Preco').text();
preco = parseFloat( preco.replace( '.', '' ).replace( ',', '.' ) );
if( preco > 199 ) {
  $('#Res').text( 'Mais que 199' );
} else {
  $('#Res').text( 'Menor ou igual a 199' );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="Preco">199,50</span>
<span id="Res"></span>
```

Comment: @Gladson Links de interesse: Sandbox para testes: http://jsfiddle.net/3pyt8hkd/ - FAQ da Comunidade: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/699 - e bem vindo ao SOpt!